# angular 4 - Update view when variable change

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi all i have a question about Angular detection.

I have this sample for you:
https://plnkr.co/edit/WiCL6qBxSgdvjaZFOgKn?p=preview

When i'm update the lsIsOpen variable (click on the valider button), Angular not update the view.

```
  public updateData(index, content):void {
this.laBonusRateData[index].content = content;
//Not work
//this.lsIsOpen = 'toto';

//Works
setTimeout(() => {
  this.lsIsOpen = null;
}, 1);
```

}

Can you explain to me why? i'm lost :(

Comment: what's suposed to update?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is that your click function showElem is bind to whole row. What happens is that if you click on valider then updateData and showElem is called. With setTimeout you set it after showElem was called. Better solution would be that showElem is not bind to whole column.

Try this for your template:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <tbody class="QTZ_default_table_font-bold">
        lsIsOpen : {{lsIsOpen}}
        <tr *ngFor="let bonusType of laBonusRateData; let idx = index">
          <td> <!-- here no click function -->
          <span (click)="showElem('item-'+idx)">items {{this.idx}}</span> <!-- CLICK ONLY ON ITEMS, NOT ON ROW -->
          <div *ngIf="lsIsOpen === ('item-'+idx)">
            <form ngForm="bonus_form" #bonus_form>
              <input type="input" name="content" size="1" [value]="laBonusRateData[idx].content" #content> <a (click)="updateData(idx, content.value)">valider</a>
            </form>
          </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      `
    })
```